# Can't reproduce SqlAzureExecutionStrategy exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, exception

I had [SqlAzureExecutionStrategy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlazureexecutionstrategy%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) exception and I can't reproduce it. According to the documentation, it's used for **[transient](https://www.google.se/search?q=definition+transient&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=55-PVqPrHsbJsQGlpqjgDg)** failures, so reproducing it might be difficult.

I've runt the process in Azure, so I hope there's some log or something that will tell me more details. I haven't found anything like that in the portal. Where is that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself (so I may be completely wrong here - If I am, please let me know :)).

Further it is my understanding is that you want to test is the execution strategy you have defined is working or not in terms of retries, number of retries and delay between the retries.

You're correct in your observation that it is quite difficult to simulate transient errors simply because things are not in your control. However looking at the documentation and some examples, what you could do is override [`SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.ShouldRetryOn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlazureexecutionstrategy.shouldretryon(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.ShouldRetryOn(System.Exception)) and insert your custom logic for failure. So you could possibly add `Failed Login` attempt as a transient error and then see if this thing is working out for you (as far as retries and delays in retries are concerned).

Consider this example ([`source`](http://ritzlgrmft.blogspot.in/2014/03/working-with-sqlazureexecutionstrategy.html)) where the author treated `SqlError with Number == -2` as a transient error.

```
protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception exception)
{
  bool shouldRetry = false;

  SqlException sqlException = exception as SqlException;
  if (sqlException != null)
  {
    foreach (SqlError error in sqlException.Errors)
    {
      if (error.Number == -2)
        shouldRetry = true;
    }
  }

  shouldRetry = shouldRetry || base.ShouldRetryOn(exception);

  Logger.WriteLog("ShouldRetryOn: " + shouldRetry);
  return shouldRetry;
}
```